# How are Hidden Abilities passed down in Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

So, I have a male Talonflame with its Hidden Ability (Gale Wings) and a female Pelipper with a normal ability (Keen Eye). I'm trying to breed a Wingull with a Hidden Ability but I can't pass down one even though they are in the same egg group. Does the female have to have the Hidden Ability to pass down to the Wingull?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when breeding Pokémon of different species, only the female is able to pass down their Hidden Ability to the offspring. The only instance when a male is able to pass down their Hidden Ability is when breeding with a Ditto.

Comment: IIRC, the male is also able to pass down their HA when they breed with a female of the same species.

Comment: @SGR It doesn't seem like it. Both Serebii and Bulbapedia say that males can only pass down their ability if they breed with a Ditto.

Comment: Danmaku is right, if two Pokemon of the same species breed only the female can pass down the HA.